# Accommodation for unaccompanied teenager in Tokyo

Tags: accommodation, tokyo, solo-travel, minors

I'm a 16-year-old wanting to go alone to Tokyo for three to four weeks, around July. As to be expected, my parents are concerned about my safety while overseas.

A standard hotel is not going to cut it. More precisely, there would need to be a "guardian" or some kind of manager on the spot, someone that would for example: make sure I'm there at night, would be able to give directions or advice about "red-light"/dangerous places in town, be able to call the police if things go down the fan, and be reachable by my parents. Basically, be a link and a guarantee for them.

My first guess would be a youth hostel, but as a kind of "lone wolf" I would rather be in a more private-ish place (a room for one).

**Is there any place in Tokyo that offers this kind of service ? If so, could you name it ?**

Otherwise, do you think I'm better off looking for homestay or just deal with it and find a hostel?

I've already sent a mail to Sakura Hotels in order to know for them, and I will update if I find anything.

Comment: Most Japanese hostels offer private rooms if you're willing to pay a bit extra.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to go the homestay route (which I think would be by far the best in your situation), I have had luck on [this site](http://www.homestayweb.com/index_japan.cgi) (but maybe that was just luck, I have used it only once).

There is a small fee to be able to send e-mails to potential hosts  (probably to cover the website costs), but you only need to do it for the first e-mail, after that they will (hopefully) answer you by e-mail and you no longer need to go through the site. Note that many hosts accept only females.